# PhpStorm SSH session root path doesn't work

Tags: ssh, terminal, phpstorm, sftp

I run JetBrains PhpStorm 2019.1 x64. Trying to connect to remote SSH server terminal with "Tools -> Start SSH session". The setting looks like this:

[image]

So I specify root path. But terminal session starts always from `/root` directory. Is there a way to force terminal to start from specific directory?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's no way yet unfortunately. You can vote for a corresponding report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-11878 to increase its priority.